# How handle the error and complete with `tap` operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store, rxjs-observables

Here is my `tap` operator with `next`, `error` and `complete`, though there is no `error` always it's called. so my `users` always empty.  how to use the `tap` operator with correct way?

```
readonly fetchUsers$ = this.effect(($) =>
$.pipe(
  tap(() => this.setState({ users: [], status: 'authenticating' })),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.dataService.getUsers().pipe(
      tap({
        next: (data: UserProps[]) => {
          this.setUsers(data);
        },
        error: () => this.setState({ users: [], status: 'error' }),//always called
        finalize: (data:UserProps[]) => this.setState({ users: data, status: 'complete' }),
      }),
      catchError(() => EMPTY)
    )
  )
)
```

);

Answer (score 1):

You're code is correct. If `error` is called, your service is throwing an error on the observable.

An example to reproduce :

```
of('World')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => throwError(() => new Error('lala'))),
    tap({
      next: (a) => console.log(a),  // nothing
      error: (a) => console.error(a), // log error
    }),
    catchError(() => EMPTY)
  )
  .subscribe();


// This one will log fine
of('World')
  .pipe(
    tap({
      next: (a) => console.log(a), // log
      error: (a) => console.error(a), // nothing
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3wbjy4?file=index.ts)